# Azure Website Deploy Error: install.js: Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-ia32.msi

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

Right now, I am trying to set up Node.js website connect to Azure SQL(Not MySQL).

I have created a simple program to get data from Azure mssql database.
On local it works fine.(It retrieves info from Azure MSSQL)

However, when I try to deploy, I get "deployment error".

Here is the gist of error I get.

```
npm ERR! weird error 1
install.js: Unable to download msnodesql-0.2.1-v0.10-ia32.msi
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.21\node.exe" "D:\Program     Files (x86)\npm\1.3.11\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm
```

My package.js is as follows

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "jade": "*",
    "nconf": "~0.6.9"
  }
}
```

Inside, node_modules, there is also mnodesql folder which I downloaded from GitHub[https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver]
I run the following code too.

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

I would appreciate any advice you can offer. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `node-sqlserver` needs C++ environment to compile the source code but there's no C++ compiler in Azure Website. What I did is to compile this module on local machine and upload as part of my source code. I covered this scenario at the bottom of my blog http://wblo.gs/dLo.

Hope this helps.